# Can't access controller variables on CodeIgniter view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I swear I'm always baffled by how CodeIgniter is passing controller variables to their views, and every project I do in it I keep running into the same stupid problem.

Here is my model:

```
public function get_post() {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active='y' AND head=1 LIMIT 1";

   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   return $query->row();
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function get_head() {
  $this->load->model('home_model');
  $data['head'] = $this->home_model->get_post();
  $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
}
```

And when I do var_dump($head) on my view I get:

```
object(stdClass)#18 (16) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["member_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["title"]=> string(131) "This is a test title" ["slug"]=> string(0) "this-is-a-test-title" ["body"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(7) "singles" ["orig_photo_name"]=> string(142) "sample.jpg" ["photo"]=> string(24) "14004803271605326007.jpg" ["comments"]=> string(1) "y" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-06-17 02:18:47" ["head"]=> string(1) "1" ["views"]=> string(2) "50" ["notes"]=> string(0) "" ["nsfw"]=> string(1) "y" ["active"]=> string(1) "y" }
```

And finally when trying to access something like title:

```
<?php echo $title; ?>

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: title

Filename: views/home_view.php

Line Number: 8
```

Any ideas other than switching to CakePHP?

Comment: How would switching between two of the worst PHP frameworks make sure that you have defined a variable in the template.

Comment: @tereško You're right. I should have said switch to Python.

Comment: @user3423909 why not to [Laravel](http://laravel.com/), recently I changed to it, coming from `Codeigniter` and found everything is more enjoyable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$query->row()` will return object so try to access on view

```
echo $head->id;
echo $head->title;
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to do $head['title'] which was giving me even more errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
First You change the model query like this 
public function get_post() {
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE active='y' AND head=1 LIMIT 1";
   $query = $this->db->query($sql);
   return $query->row_array(); //this is return value in array
}

Then call function in Controller

public function get_head() {
  $this->load->model('home_model');
  $data['head'] = $this->home_model->get_post();
  $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
}

Then get value in view 
<?php echo $head['id']; ?>
```